# Django Caching - Remove caching for certain pages

Tags: django, caching, memcached

I would like to turn caching off for certain pages when that view is accessed. It's for a page that simply queries model objects.

it seems like when 
        'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
is enabled, it requires another "refresh" from the browser to see the latest data.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers

> If you want to use headers to disable caching altogether,
>   django.views.decorators.cache.never_cache is a view decorator that
>   adds headers to ensure the response won't be cached by browsers or
>   other caches. Example:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def myview(request):
     # ...
```